# Set the default form data keys with an empty string

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, input, pinia

**How can I Set the Pinia default form data keys with an empty string. Into the state User object I need to push the firstName and lastName default values as an empty string. But I can't see how ti implement it with typeScript.*

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

type User = {
  firstName: string  //set firstName defaut value to '' 
  lastName: string   //set firstName defaut value to ''
}

export const useForm = defineStore(
  {
  id: 'login',
  state: () => ({
    User: <User[]>[]  // fill User with firstName and lastName  keys from type User = {}
  }),
```

*

Comment: User != User[]. do you need an array or a single user?

Comment: If you want to have defaults, classes are better for this, then you can have properties that have default values or you can set them in the contructor

Comment: you could then have a public method getFullName which returns the full name, users.map(u => u.getFullName())

Answer (score 0):

This will get you part way to your final solution, you just have to take the concattedUserList and return that as your state.

You must use a class to achieve what you want as that will allow default properties and also a method for returning the full name

```
class User {
    constructor(public firstName: string = '', public lastName: string = '') {}

    public fullName(): string {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`.trim();
    }
}

// For the first user, we have not passed in a first or second name so it defaults to empty string
const users = [new User(), new User('bob', 'marley'), new User('sandra', 'jackson')];

const concattedUserList = users.map((u) => u.fullName());

console.log(concattedUserList);
```

returns

```
[ '', 'bob marley', 'sandra jackson' ]
```

its probably best to filter the ones which are blank

```
const concattedUserList = users.map((u) => u.fullName()).filter(n=> n !== '')
```